# Data truncated and incorrect integer value errors

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, go, go-gorm

With GORM I want to use `uuid` as primary key rather than default incrementing integer. My model:

```
type User struct {
    ID       string `gorm:"primaryKey" sql:"type:uuid;primary_key;default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
    Username string `json:"username" gorm:"unique"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

// This is a Gorm hook.
func (u *User) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    u.ID = uuid.NewString()
    return nil
}
```

When I insert into SQLite the data gets inserted but when I insert into a MySQL database I get errors:

1. Error 1265: Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1
2. Error 1366: Incorrect integer value: 'e2d63365-6876-4183-bd81-6deb3e3906e6' for column 'id' at row 1
3. Error 1264: Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1

The command GORM is creating:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`username`,`password`) VALUES ('4de44e7e-b658-4225-b654-296d4e60624c','joe_mama','supersecret')
```

I've found other posts about such errors but they're all SQL focused which I really can't do anything about since Gorm handles that.

Comment: Update your question with this query result from MySQL `SHOW CREATE TABLE users;`

Comment: Please heed the requests of the commenters — double-check that MySQL created the table as you think it did. The error suggests that MySQL created a table with an integer `id` column, despite your intention to declare it to be string.

Comment: @FanoFN I did the command you suggested and it showed that the schema of the model in my database was still using the auto_increment integer id. I dropped the table and all is well. Thank you! If you want, you can write an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: That's good to know. I didn't do much though so I don't think I should get the points for answering. Here's what you can do, you can post your own answer - according to your own understanding of what happened and how you solved it then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @FanoFN, I ran the following command:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE users;
```

This showed the schema of the model and it showed that my table was using an older schema which I had implemented previously.

**The solution** ended up being to just drop the users table and remigrate the model.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I had too this error. I update my script to change the type int to varchar(), but when i run 'describe mytable' the type of the value was int. I drop the table and then it run smoothly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).